# :firstclass rule used in tutorial, and in need of clarification as to why

Tags: css, flexbox

I am running through some tutorials on treehouse - this one on [flexbox navigation](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/css-layout-techniques/flexbox-layout/build-a-navigation-with-flexbox)

and I stumbled across some code that I saw that I couldn't figure the need for.  The guide was using this rule to size the logo in the flexbox navigaton (the two are nested in the tutorial):

```
.main-logo:first-child{
    margin-right: 50px;
    flex-grow: 1.5;
}
```

The since the first child of the logo would be the .main-nav list items, he would technically be targeting the first list item on the list in the nav bar, correct?  For some reason though, the values and properties are indeed effecting the logo itself and not the list item that is seemingly being targeted with the rule.  What am I overlooking that makes this the case?  Thanks!

Here's a fiddle of the sample project:  http://jsfiddle.net/u7rb0gzd/

The rule is on line 97 of the CSS.  The project works fine, I am just having trouble figuring out why this certain rule works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:first-child` rule selector targets elements which are the first child of their parent element. Hence when you use `.main-logo:first-child`, you are selecting any elements with the class `.main-logo` that are the first child of their parent element.

Supposing you had the following HTML:

```
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

You would be able to color the first list item red with the following CSS:

```
.main-nav li:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I understand the first-child pseudo-class itself, but how does .main-logo:first-child style the main logo itself in this example when it is selecting the children of the logo?

Comment: `.main-logo` isn't the parent element! It is a sibling of the other `li` elements (look closely). `.main-logo` is also the `li:first-child` of `.main-nav`

Answer (score 1):

`:first-child` will target the first element of the rule for each of theyr parents, consider the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

And the following style:

```
ul li:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

This would apply the color red, to the first `li` element of each `ul`:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li> -> red
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>a</li> -> red
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I understand the first-child pseudo-class itself, but how does .main-logo:first-child style the main logo itself in this example when it is selecting the children of the logo?

Comment: I'ts not selecting the children of the logo, it's selecting the first element with class .main-logo